# Stacking GWT layouts on top of one another

Tags: gwt, layout, web, toolkit

I'm trying to build a GWT GUI, but I'm not sure if it's possible.  Basically, I need to be able to stack three layouts/panels, one on top of another like this:

```
Bottom Layout: Panel that fills the whole screen (will actually contain SVG stuff).
Middle Layout: DockLayoutPanel with tools docked around the edges, also full screen.
Top Layout: Transparent panel, again filling the whole screen.
```

Is it possible to stack panels like this? I assume I could use AbsolutePanel to do it somehow, but I was hoping for a nicer solution.
Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want a `DockLayoutPanel` inside, try with a `LayoutPanel` (or the `RootLayoutPanel`) and simply add your widgets in order as, by default, a child of a `LayoutPanel` [fills its parent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html#add%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that's done the trick. I didn't realise LayoutPanel was so powerful!